# Apache POI create a constraint to verify if an entered cell text is like a given pattern

Tags: java, excel, validation, apache-poi, constraints

I would like to know if there is a way to solve this problem: I want to create an excel file in which the cell should have one of the given values, with a drop down list:

a) "first value"

b) "second value"

c) "word1 word2 XX.YY.ZZZZ"

where XX is the day, YY the month and ZZZZ the year. I tried DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint  and DVConstraint.createFormulaListConstraint methods but without good results.
Thank you very much for your help. 
This is my code:

```
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, table.size(), 14, 14);
DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint( new String[]{"Risolta", "Falso positivo", "Accettazione/Assunzione del rischio", "Soluzione non applicabile", "Rientro entro XX.YY.ZZZZ"});
DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```

Comment: Please share what you have done... This will help us to answer...

Comment: I edited the question with the code I have tried. Thanks a lot.

Comment: where's the code where you add the data validation to the sheet?

Comment: I added the instruction which adds the data validation

Answer (score 0):

It is not giving you positive result because constraints array can take 256 character all together. If it is more than that, you won't get dropdown.
Reference : [Is there a max number items while generating drop down list in Excel using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630507/is-there-a-max-number-items-while-generating-drop-down-list-in-excel-using-apach)

Comment: Ok but this question is still open. Even if there is a limited number of items in the dropdown, how can we ensure the user does not put another value manually? Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Is what you suggested when using: validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint ?